# How to draw object under line?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have Line in unity. She's size 64 dots.In fact, what is the point, but the point is that I need to paint over the area under the line similar to spriteShape, I would be happy to use it, but I still could not figure it out. here is the code for the line.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class soundVisualize : MonoBehaviour {

    public float range = 5000f;

    public int number = 64;
    public float[] oldSpc;

    public LineRenderer line;

    public int spec;

    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float speedAnimation;

    private void Awake() 
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < number; i++)
        {
            Vector3 posInArray = new Vector3(0,0,0);
            if(i>0)
                posInArray = line.GetPosition(i-1);
            line.SetPosition(i,posInArray+new Vector3(0.2f,0,0));
        }    
    }
    
    void Update () {
        float[] spectrum = new float[spec];
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().GetSpectrumData(spectrum, 0, FFTWindow.BlackmanHarris);

        for(int i = 0;i < number; i++)
        {
            line.SetPosition(i,Vector3.Lerp(line.GetPosition(i),new Vector3(line.GetPosition(i).x,(range * spectrum[i] + oldSpc[i])/2),speedAnimation));
            oldSpc[i] = range * spectrum[i];
        }
    }


}
```

we have

[image: this]

but we need

[image: this]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sorry, I don't quite understand what exactly you are trying to achieve and where exactly the issue lies .. Could you extend your description a bit? Maybe some picture would help to understand your use-case better

Comment: I expanded the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky but I'll try to explain what I'm doing ;)

Basically what you want to do would be to create a new mesh that simply contains two lines

- Your current line positions
- The bottom line

so what I do is create the mesh **once** at the beginning by creating these two lines and connecting them with triangulated faces.

Then later I simply copy the the positions of the line-renderer into the top line of the new mesh.

So it might look somewhat like

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SoundVisualizer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer line;

    // Best already reference these via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource _audioSource;
    [SerializeField] private MeshFilter _meshFilter;

    public int number = 64;
    public float[] oldSpc;
    public float range = 5000f;

    public int spec;

    [Range(0, 1)] public float speedAnimation;

    // Stores the line positions
    private Vector3[] positions;
    // Stores the mesh reference
    private Mesh _mesh;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // As fallback get it ONCE on runtime
        if (!_audioSource) _audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        if (!_meshFilter) _meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();

        _mesh = _meshFilter.mesh;

        // Set the point amount via code
        line.positionCount = number;

        // Note that it is way more efficient to use GetPositions and SetPositions
        // instead of using GetPosition and SetPosition multiple times!
        positions = new Vector3[number];
        line.GetPositions(positions);
        
        for (var i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            positions[i] = Vector3.right * (0.2f* i);
        }

        line.SetPositions(positions);

        if (spec < number) spec = number;

        oldSpc = new float[spec];

        // Now initialize the mesh once
        // After having set up all the faces etc it is enough to only update
        // The vertex positions
        InitializeMesh();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var spectrum = new float[spec];
        _audioSource.GetSpectrumData(spectrum, 0, FFTWindow.BlackmanHarris);

        // Update the values inside of the array you already have
        // -> no need to use GetPositions again
        for (var i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            var position = positions[i];

            positions[i] = Vector3.Lerp(position, new Vector3(position.x, (range * spectrum[i] + oldSpc[i]) / 2), speedAnimation);

            oldSpc[i] = range * spectrum[i];
        }

        line.SetPositions(positions);

        UpdateMesh();
    }

    private void InitializeMesh()
    {
        _mesh.Clear();

        // Basically we will create a bottom and a top line each with "number" vertices
        // Then later we create triangulated faces between these two lines
        var vertices = new Vector3[number * 2];

        for (var i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            vertices[i] = i * 0.2f * Vector3.right + Vector3.up * 1; // This will be the top line, for debugging set it to y = 1
            vertices[i + number] = i * 0.2f * Vector3.right; // This will be the bottom line
        }

        var triangles = new int[2 * (number - 1) * 3]; // This is "number - 1" * amount f faces per segment (2) * vertices per face ( 3)

        // Now lets create triangulated faces using these vertices and connecting the two lines
        for (var i = 0; i < number - 1; i++)
        {
            triangles[6 * i] = i;
            triangles[6 * i + 1] = i + 1;
            triangles[6 * i + 2] = i + number;

            triangles[6 * i + 3] = i + 1;
            triangles[6 * i + 4] = i + number + 1;
            triangles[6 * i + 5] = i + number;
        }

        _mesh.vertices = vertices;
        _mesh.triangles = triangles;
        _mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }

    private void UpdateMesh()
    {
        // Basically we will simply update the positions of the top line in the mesh
        // (= the first half of the vertices array)
        // The rest (faces etc) will be updated automatically

        var vertices = _mesh.vertices;
        for (var i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            vertices[i] = positions[i];
        }

        _mesh.vertices = vertices;
    }
}
```

So just to show it I gave the line a different color

[image]

So the last thing to do would be to adjust the thickness or in other words the offset to the bottom line. I would actually simply move down the bottom line

```
// In this line simply add some negative offset on Y
//
//                                              |
//                                              V
vertices[i + number] = i * 0.2f * Vector3.right - Vector3.up ; // This will be the bottom line
```

And now it looks like this :)

[image]

Note that in this current version you will not be able to adjust all the values of the Inspector at runtime ;)

Also note that of course the LineRenderer component is a bit more powerful since it can also automatically generate some smoothed corners and stuff

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with a LineRenderer.
You should try to create and modify it on runtime. You will have 64 triangles on the top edge and 2 triangles on bottom left corner and bottom right corner.

See official [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) for more information.